# Understanding the Calculation of InverseFourierTransform[ ]

Tags: fourier-analysis

I was looking at the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFourierTransform.html). In the "Details and Options" section they mention that $f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega)e^{-i \omega t} d\omega$. I interpreted this to mean

InverseFourierTransform[expr,$\omega$,t] = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} $ expr $ e^{-i \omega t} d\omega$

Is this correct? I tried to type in the following two expressions to confirm this but I was not getting the same results.

```
     InverseFourierTransform[1/(1 + I*\[Omega]), \[Omega], -t]
    
    (1/Sqrt[(2*Pi)]) Integrate[(1/(1 + I*\[Omega]))*
   Exp[-I*\[Omega]*t], {\[Omega], -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

What I was expecting was for both of the above expressions to give me `E^-t Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] HeavisideTheta[t]` but that isn't what happened. I tried switching Integrate[] to NIntegrate[] but then the integral won't evaluate at all.

Am I misinterpreting what InverseFourierTransform[] does? Or is there an error in my other integral? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: why would you use `-t` as the time variable? Try `InverseFourierTransform[1/(1 + I*w), w, t]`  The mapping is from `w` (frequency) to `t` (time) and not from `w` to `-t`. The Fourier transforms maps `t` to `w` and not `t` to `-w`. Try to stick to the definitions unless you want results which will not make too much sense.

Comment: @Nasser I was doing this to try to match the definition of the bilateral Laplace transform so I needed the -t. I didn't do it perfectly though I'm now seeing some other errors that I need to fix

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the results of

```
InverseFourierTransform[1/(1 + I*\[Omega]), \[Omega], t]
```

> `E^t Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] HeavisideTheta[-t]`

```
N[E^t Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] HeavisideTheta[-t] /. t -> -1]
```

> `0.922137`

and (pay you attention to `1/Sqrt[2*Pi]`, not `1/(2*Pi)`)

```
Integrate[ 1/(1 + I*\[Omega])*Exp[-I*\[Omega]*t], {\[Omega], -Infinity, 
Infinity}, Assumptions -> t > -Infinity]/Sqrt[2*Pi]
```

> `-(1/(4 \[Pi])) I ((1/Sqrt[\[Pi]])(MeijerG[{{1/2, 1, 1}, {}}, {{1}, {}}, (2 I)/ Abs[t], 1/2] -  I MeijerG[{{1/2, 1/2, 1}, {}}, {{1/2}, {}}, (2 I)/Abs[t], 1/ 2] Sign[t]) +  2 CosIntegral[ I Abs[t]] (Cosh[Abs[t]] +  Sign[t] Sinh[Abs[t]]) - (Cosh[Abs[t]] Sign[t] +  Sinh[Abs[t]]) (I \[Pi] + 2 SinhIntegral[Abs[t]]))`

```
% /. t -> -1.0000000
```

> `0.922137 + 2.21457*10^-17 I`

differ symbolically, but coincide numerically for `t==-1`.

Comment: It should be noticed that the above improper integral converges only conditionally. Because of this reason have to  handle it carefully and carefully.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Sorry about the typos. I've fixed them.